# Tapping on Watchkit Glance won't route to specific controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

This is really wield. I'm using the updateUserActivity method in Glance to route to a specific controller, and it worked fine. But today it just stopped working, and jumps to initial interface every time. The only thing I've changed is that I refactored the controllers' class names. What could go wrong?

The code in Glance:

```
- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];
    //Jump to specific controller.
    [self updateUserActivity:@"com.example.appname"
                    userInfo:@{@"controllerName": @"NewControllerName",
                               @"detailInfo": @"This is some more detailed information to pass."}
                  webpageURL:nil];
```

}

Comment: Did you update the controller's name in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes I did. The identifier, the class name, all changed.

Comment: Did you reset the simulator?

Comment: Didn't work. I just reset the simulator, restart it and xcode as well, clean, rebuild... :(

Answer (score 0):

Found it...I forgot that I not only changed the class name, I also changed the initial screen. However after the change, I didn't move the handle method to the initial controller.

```
- (void)handleUserActivity:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [self pushControllerWithName:userInfo[@"controllerName"] context:nil];
}
```